# Reducing a few forms into 1 form. Good or bad practice?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, .net-3.5

I have multiple forms and was wondering if it would be good practice to add panels to a form, copy across some of the other forms into the main form and display. For example, I could have Form1, Form2, Form3 and Form4. I would then remove Form2 and Form3 - beforehand copy elements into 2 new panels in Form1, then simply toggle between the different 'views' using location, visibility and size.

I have created a real-life example below using the same aspects:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Width = 385;
    this.Height = 243;
}

private void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Width = 541;
    this.Height = 226;

    panelSearch.Visible = false;
    panelFileInfo.Visible = true;
    panelFileInfo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 2);
    label4.Text = textBox1.Text;
}

private void labelSearchAgain_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Width = 385;
    this.Height = 243;

    textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    checkBox1.Checked = false;
    checkBox2.Checked = false;
    panelSearch.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like something you'd put on codereview, but there isn't any code, which also makes it invalid here. It doesn't belong in UX because it's apparently a question about coding best practices... I'm at a loss.

Comment: I have never heard of that. It's not invalid, how? I only simply created forms and two panels, then produced a screenshot of the outlook. In Form1.cs the code is default... I have added nothing code-wise as I just used the tools. So why should I have uploaded some code that is already default when you create a new form? This is just a simple example to show the use of panels.

Comment: Is that the point of StackOverflow? People come here when their code has issues, and generally questions with no code are not SO's domain. This might be a valid question here but if so, it's rather close.

Comment: I understand your point, I didn't think code was needed to represent my example as i wanted to show the design aspect more-so. So i will update my question shortly with some code I have used in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to componentize creating custom components/usercontrols that aggregate 2 or 3 controls. I then work on these new components to make them highly reusable (at least inside the same project) with design time support and so on...

I suggest you to try to convert your forms in controls, then drag and drop your custom controls in your main form

Comment: This is brilliant, but I don't think I can use UserControls for it... In my project I can change language from a choice of 21 :/ So I don't recon using this will work... But will keep this in mind for future projects! You've opened my eyes!

Comment: UserControls support multilanguage as well as Forms do. It's very simple GUI task.

Comment: That's great, I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, we've got a *lot* of legacy code at work where someone did just what you're trying to do. They combined a dozen distinct forms into one huge form with panels everywhere that were dynamically shown/hidden, moved around and manipulated.

It has become a maintenance nightmare!

Keep the forms separated according to their functionality. Give them good descriptive names. And if you're just starting out a project, you might consider putting your efforts into learning WPF, as it is the natural successor to WinForms.

This is all based on my opinion of course, but it's also based on 5 years of experience maintaining some spaghetti code, and I'd recommend you try to avoid it.

Comment: I would also advise against that. In Winforms it should become ugly very fast. WPF combined with a good Toolkit like Caliburn..Micro would be a maintainable fit to this problem.#